# Foundation 6 sticky menu. Left menu div pushes up when page is scrolled back to top

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

So i have a sticky navigation bar and when the page is scrolled down and back up the right hand nav stays put but the rest is pushed upwards off screen. i've tried all sorts but just can't figure it out, i'm assuming i've over looked something so hope the guys can help.

### HTML:

```
<div data-sticky-container>
  <div class="title-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%">
    <div class="title-bar-left">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-text">TITLE</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="title-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Haven't included any CSS as it's back to the standard CSS in the Foundation files.

Hope that's enough to go on and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, this style fix worked for me:

```
.sticky.is-anchored { 
    bottom: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out when i'm home and let you know if it fixes it for me.

Comment: Worked a treat, Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Can also be solved by creating a sub-element with the background-property:

```
<div class="sticky">
    <div style="background-color: blue">...</div>
</div>
```